# Use Constants in XAML WPF C# occur MarkupExtensions error

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in a project called `Common` and there I have a `Constants` class:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public class ListViewContextMenu
    {
        public const string ADD = "addToolStripMenuItem";
        public const string RENAME = "renameToolStripMenuItem";
        public const string DISABLE = "disableToolStripMenuItem";
        public const string DELETE = "deleteToolStripMenuItem";

        public const string ADD_TEXT = "Add";
        public const string RENAME_TEXT = "Rename";
        public const string DISABLE_TEXT = "Disable";
        public const string ENABLE_TEXT = "Enable";
    }
}
```

In other project, where is WPF, I want to use above constant in context menu header:

```
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"
```

and

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Name="listView1" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding TrackerList,Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Title">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="lv_ctx">
            <MenuItem Header="Add" Name="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.ADD}"></MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.RENAME_TEXT}" Name="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.RENAME}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.DELETE_TEXT}" Name="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.DELETE}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.DISABLE_TEXT}" Name="{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.DISABLE}"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

But I get error:

> MarkupExtensions are not allowed for Uid or Name property values, so
>   '{x:Static constants:Constants+ListViewContextMenu.ADD}' is not valid.

I expected to work since those are constants...

Comment: Could it be because the `ListViewContextMenu` needs to be static as well? I'm not able to try this out at the moment, it was just my first thought.

Comment: I made those subclasses as static and same error occur at runtime

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to bind the `Name` property of an object (even if you are using `Static` Markup extension). Two reasons come to my mind: `FindName()` `ContextMenu` method won't work and you cannot refer the controls from your code-behind if their names are dynamic (i.e. they can change at run time), because the name is not known at building time.

I guess the exception that is thrown is meant to prevent those issues.

If you need to use those constants in your `MenuItems`, you can consider using `Tag` property. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

`x:Static` is a markup extension.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/markup-extensions-and-wpf-xaml

I think it doesn't matter what x:Static is returning.  The parser is checking for any markup extension and raising that error.

Whoever designed the parser decided that it was a good idea if the unique identifier for a ui object was right there in xaml as a string.

I can't see why you'd want to abstract Name in this way.

If the Name is set there in xaml then you can see it as you read the xaml. If your approach worked then you would need to go find the value in some other class.
All that abstracting seems to be achieving is making it harder to read the xaml. I see that as a negative, myself.

I think it's also worth explaining best practice.

Meaning MVVM for the vast majority of wpf dev teams.

A much more usual way of working would be to bind a collection of viewmodels to the itemssource of a menu.  They would expose icommand and description bound to command and Header of the menuitem.  No need to know the name of any menuitem clicked because it invokes the bound icommand.

Comment: Right, it's more like a variable name than a string. You don't abstract away the variable name.